# Convert custom API to Ruby on Rails ActiveResource

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, xml-rpc, activeresource

I have a set of embedded devices that run software written in c++. The API to communicate the devices is simple: get/set/acquire parameters and signals.

I'd like to implement common web application to access all of the devices from a single point.

My idea was to add XML RPC interface to devices and then use ActiveResource to access devices from the web server. This combination doesn't seem to be used at all in practice.

I'm free to choose any protocol inside the devices. What are your recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already considering XML RPC I'm assuming you have some sort of web server running on the device. I would probably choose a RESTful web service over XML RPC. If designed carefully you could have corresponding services on your Rails app.

For example:

`http://somedevice/signals.json` - gets all signals

`http://yourrailsapp/somedevice/signals.json` - gets somedevice's signals; you could use an id instead here if that makes more sense (`http://yourrailsapp/devices/1/signals.json`).

Comment: At this point I don't have any web server (service) running on the devices. I was thinking to add something very lightweight, even better embeddable that can speak a protocol, understood by Rails. The devices would perform just translation between the internal custom API and the web service. Is there a C/C++ library available that can serve JSON?

Comment: Don't get too caught up on the data format itself. XML is fine, I just prefer to use json where I can. I'm only slightly familiar with XML RPC but from what I understand it requires http (hence my assumption about some sort of web server running on your device).

Comment: I will use a c++ http library like http://www.pion.org/projects/pion-network-library and implement restful web service with it. I will use the format that is easiest to integrate with Rail 3.

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't find much XML RPC stuff in the Rails community. Rails itself really pushes you towards RESTful web services. Specifically a resource-oriented RESTful architecture. There are [great books](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260) out there about it but it comes down to using http methods (get, put, post, delete) instead of passing parameters and then some intelligent URLS.